# ETXTBSY: text file is busy when running npm install (via Vagrant with Unix - Desktop OS is Windows)

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, npm-install, scotchbox

I am working from a Windows 7 Desktop that is running a Vagrant box with 'Scotchbox 2.0' (A Vagrant LAMP Stack) and it works fine pretty much.
- https://box.scotch.io

Within my vagrant box I have the `node 11.0.0` & `npm 6.4.1` installed - the latest versions at this point.

I have a directory that has a package.json file - I run `npm install` to download all the dependencies after a short time I get the following message in the terminal:

```
npm WARN rollback Rolling back copy-descriptor@0.1.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ETXTBSY: text file is busy, unlink '/var/www/exec/posting/node_modules/copy-descriptor/package.json.3200674018'
npm ERR! path /var/www/exec/posting/node_modules/copy-descriptor/package.json.3200674018
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename '/var/www/exec/posting/node_modules/copy-descriptor/package.json.3200674018' -> '/var/www/exec/posting/node_modules/copy-descriptor/package.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-10-30T12_20_53_534Z-debug.log
```

I have tried doing the `unlink` command to the file it states and re-running `npm install` but then I get the same error (but with more packages) as shown above how do I fix this error?

Similar issues here :-
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20605

Answer (score 0):

downgrading working for me as well.

Here is how I downgraded:

npm install -g npm@5.7.1